# Birt - Using Amazon Javascript SDK In Report

Tags: birt

I am very new to Birt just started two weeks ago, I could not find any related topics in the forums so I am posting a new one, please share the reference if the issue has already been discussed,

I have some image files stored in Amazon S3 bucket which uses secured URLs, so I can not simply embed them, it says access denied, for that purpose I have to use AWS Javascript SDK whcih allows me to pass the Sceret and Access key and the file I want to access to get a Pre-signed url which I can use anywhere to get that file,

so far all good,

now I want to do authentication and get the pre-signed url in the report for that I have to include this sdk javascipt aws-sdk-2.1.45.min.js file in report and thats where I am stuck,

I have tried adding javascript sdk using report Resources

but report does not even run may be some other javascript conflcts, I get en error

Then I tried to add this JS using Text element

Now the sdk is included in the report

But when I try to use the javascript code

it gives an error that AWS undefined,

I have also tried using report's clientScript section head.js(), here everything works fine but how do I access the object  that I get after authentication in the report

```
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'xxxxx', secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'});

AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';

var s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

so I can pass the image secured url (which is in database) to s3 object and get a public url using this authentication object
and set it back to image the URL,

If anyone has some ideas please share, where I am doing mistake,

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [AWS sdk **for java**](https://aws.amazon.com/en/sdk-for-java/), not javascript. Download it, add aws-java-sdk-1.10.11.jar and its dependencies to jar-resources of the report or to you class-path. This way you will be able to invoke AWS api in all regular BIRT expressions, even in a computed column of a dataset.

```
importPackage(Packages.com.amazonaws.services.s3);
var s3=new AmazonS3Client();
```

However with a javascript API as you tried so far, AWS is invoked from a client-side perspective and results can't be processed on server-side. It could still be possible (but painful) to display images in HTML format, but not in PDF and Office formats.